# Assigning default value for jQuery End_DateTimePicker (xdsoft) from Start_DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetimepicker

I have integrated the xdsoft datetimepicker jQuery plugin into my MVC application but would like to set the default value for the 'datetimepickerEnd' to the value of the 'datetimepickerStart' Below are the jQuery functions and the html tags where I call them. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // XDSoft DateTimePicker
    jQuery(function () {
        var start = jQuery("#datetimepickerStart").datetimepicker({
            // on change set default for datetimepickerEnd
        });
        var end = jQuery("#datetimepickerEnd").datetimepicker({
            // default to whatever datetimepickerStart value
        });
    });
</script>

                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Start_DateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "< Click to open DateTimePicker >", id = "datetimepickerStart" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start_DateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.End_DateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "< Click to open DateTimePicker >", id = "datetimepickerEnd" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.End_DateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("EndDateError", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't this just about jquery and not ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I have configured this plugin into my MVC application therefore I thought it would be helpful to include in the tagging.